# How to pass array of structs from main to another function

Tags: c, arrays

Im I have this array of structs that I am trying to pass to another function (setup) in my C program. The array is created and populated in the main function. I would make it global but I don't know the size of the array until the program starts, as it takes input from command line args. The setup function will run in main. Since the array gets populated before `setup()` runs in main, how do I access the contents of `array1` in `setup()`.

Essentially:

```
void setup()
{
   //Wanting to access array in here
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct examples array1[count-2];

    // Calculation occurs here and fills array1
    
    setup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pass it as parameter

Comment: what does that look like? Will it be able to if its not global

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a pointer to the struct along with an optional size parameter in the `setup` function.

```
void setup(struct examples *arr, int size)
{
  ..
}

// in main
setup(array1, count-2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the pointer of that array to function, pointer is the position of data in memory, for arrays you need to pass only the name of array

```
void setup(struct examples* array, int count)
{
    int i=0;
    for(;i<count;i++) {
        //Do something
        array[i] 

    }
   //Wanting to access array in here
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    struct examples array1[count-2];

    // Calculation occurs here and fills array1

    setup(array1,count-2);
    return 0;
}
```

I also passed the size of the array to help manipulate it in the function

Answer (score 0):

Simply send the array as a param to setup() method.

```
setup(array1); //in main function

void setup(struct array1[])
{
   //process array1 here
}
```